# Button and Edittext styles differ between real phone (Galaxy S2) and emulator

Tags: android, view

On the AVD, my buttons and edittexts look very nice with rounded corners and shaded backgrounds. Also in the gui editor of Eclipse, they look nice as it should be.

But when I then install the app on my SGS2, the buttons and edittexts are basically just white rectangles.

App is compiled for Android 1.6. SGS2 runs Android 2.3.3.

-- As a newbie, I don't seem to be allowed to post the screen images, bummer, sorry about that --
Here is the XML. I didn't do any special formatting:

```
                  <EditText android:id="@+id/from_account" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:text="Checking"/>
```

I thought it may be due to differences in screen resolution and density. But they are the same except xdpi and ydpi (see images). (Please ignore color of DisplayMetrics).

Comment: It's seems that workaround is to set element's `style` property individually

Answer (score 2):

That's because each manufacturer defines it's own default theme.
[Read more about themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).

Comment: Yes indeed, Samsung seems to have changed the default Android styles. As Joseph suggested below, I copied the default Android styles into my project and voila, it now looks the same as in Eclipse and in the emulator. (Including the ugly orange highlights :-)

Comment: So, apparently Samsung has done a less than optimal job in customizing the styles. Is there any smart way to restore the default Android styles? (without rooting the phone?) It is a drag to have to override Samsungs stuff.

Comment: I don't think that is any way except using the original android files. Just remember that you have different android versions and each one uses a different set of colors for styling. Probably when ICS launches, the styles in the source tree should be all different than what you have now.

Answer (score 0):

As @renam.antunes said - each manufacturer is free to customize the theme as they see like.

If you want more control, then you'll need to style the components yourself - e.g. setting the background of image of a button. If you like the default Android style you can find the resources used for that in sdk/platforms/platform-X/data/res/